# Firebase totaly avoid node or not?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

According to the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data), we should avoid nesting data. With this in mind, I wonder what is the best practice, for my database, to store then find this data.

I have to store some "activities". Each "Activity" belongs to a "notion" and each "notion" belongs to a "type".
With this in mind, what is the best way to store all the activities for a fast access?

```
"Type_1" : {
    "Notion_1" : {
        "Activity_1" : "....",
        "Activity_1" : "...."
    },
    "Notion_2" : {
        "Activity_1" : "....",
        "Activity_2" : "...."
    }
},
"Type_2" : {
    "Notion_1" : {
        "Activity_1" : "....",
        "Activity_1" : "...."
    },
    "Notion_2" : {
        "Activity_1" : "....",
        "Activity_2" : "...."
    }
}
```

}

or

```
"Type_1_notion_1_activity_1" : { "content" : "...." },
"Type_1_notion_1_activity_2" : { "content" : "...." },
"Type_1_notion_2_activity_1" : { "content" : "...." },
"Type_1_notion_2_activity_2" : { "content" : "...." },

"Type_2_notion_1_activity_1" : { "content" : "...." },
"Type_2_notion_1_activity_2" : { "content" : "...." },
"Type_2_notion_2_activity_1" : { "content" : "...." },
"Type_2_notion_2_activity_2" : { "content" : "...." },
```

I wanted to use this to get the data

```
firebase.database().ref("/main/" + activityUID).once('value', function(snap) {...}
```

Where activityUID is either `["Type_1_notion_1_activity_1"]` or `["Type_1/Notion_1/Activity_1"]`.

Is it a good method? Thank you!

Comment: While it does say to avoid nesting data the guide also provides examples as to WHEN to avoid it, not completely avoid it. There are many cases where nesting data is an appropriate and proper structure. It's totally dependent on your use case so don't denormalize your data just 'cause it looks cool. There should be a reason to do so. Unfortunately there's no way to answer your question; 'fast access' is subjective and based upon what's being done with the data. The best structure is again based on what's being done with the data. If you can provide details and some code, we may be able to help.

Comment: As Jay said: there is no single answer about "what data structure is best", since it all depends on the use-case of your app. For good introductions to the topic, read [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and view [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s).